# Hide Page Layouts and Import SpreadSheet

Tags: page-layout

I would like to hide the standard Page and Web Part Page layouts in the create page and only use Publishing Page. I tried the SetAvailablePageLayouts but that doesn't work. I'm also trying to hide the Import Spreadsheet option but can't find a corresponding feature for that option. Have anybody here succeded with that?

Best regards,
Niclas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was to hide "More Options" in site actions and make an own "Create Page" site action that redirected the user to CreatePage.aspx where only our page layouts where shown.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure witch SharePoint version your asking about. So this is for SharePoint 2010.

go to Site Settings > Page Layout and Site Template Settings.

Select "Pages in this site can only use the following layouts:" and select the publishing pages (Article Page) you would like. Also you can select the default page layout in the section below that.

[image: PageLayout]

Comment: Hi 

Yes, I know that but that doesn't apply to Page and Web Part page if you choose Site Actions - More Options. http://i47.tinypic.com/b66eef.png